# Android TabLayout and onClick FragmentTransaction and saving state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I've been racking my brain on this and I'm hoping someone can shed some light. I have an activity with a tab layout, which has 3 tabs. Each tab is its own fragment. The third tad has a recycler view. In the recyclerviews adapter I have an onClickListener which will launch a new fragment in place the current fragment. If the phone is rotated the view is recreated with both fragments(one over the other). I'm messing something up with the saving states or saving wrong one.  Any ideas on how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code.

Activity:

```
public class EmergencyDisclosureGuideActivity extends BaseActivity {

private static final String TAG = EmergencyDisclosureGuideActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
private ServiceProvidersDetailFragment mServiceProvidersDetailFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContent);

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_fixed_tabs, null);
    mFrameLayout.addView(view);

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    setupViewPager(mViewPager);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    }

    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.fixedTabs);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("2702 Emergency Disclosure Guide");
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState: " + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);


}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFrag(new Introduction2702Fragment(), "INTRO");
    adapter.addFrag(new HowTo2702Fragment(), "HOW-TO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ServiceProviders2702FragmentHolder(), "SERVICE PROVIDERS");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}



private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {

        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.action_about) {
        displayAbout();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstance);

    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState: " + mViewPager.getCurrentItem());
    savedInstance.putInt("CurrentPosition", mViewPager.getCurrentItem());

}
```

Third Fragment:

```
public class ServiceProviders2702FragmentHolder extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = ServiceProviders2702FragmentHolder.class.getSimpleName();
private FrameLayout mFrameLayout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_holder, container, false);

    initView(view);

    return view;
}

private void initView(View view) {

    mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.flFragmentHolder);

    Fragment serviceProviders = new ServiceProviders2702Fragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(AppConstants.SENDING_ACTIVITY, "MainActivity");
    serviceProviders.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.flFragmentHolder, serviceProviders).commit();

}
```

Adapter onClick:

```
mResources = mContext.getResources();
                String[] howTos = mResources.getStringArray(R.array.facebook);
                Fragment serviceProviders = new ServiceProvidersDetailFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("Service Provider", "Facebook");
                args.putStringArray("How-Tos", howTos);
                serviceProviders.setArguments(args);

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((EmergencyDisclosureGuideActivity) mContext).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentHolder, serviceProviders).commit();
```

Comment: Can you narrow down your question please? What is the expected result? What do you mean by "messing something up with the saving states"?

Comment: Sorry, Let me try and put it in steps and hopefully you;ll get what I mean.
1. Activity launches (tab layout)
2. Swipe to 3rd tab (recycler view with providers)
3. click a provider and get new detail fragment in place of recycler view fragment(this is done with fragmentTransaction.replace)
4. rotate phone and still be in the detail fragment.
At the moment, when phone is rotated both the recycler view and the detail view are seen one on top of the other.  Hope this helps, thanks!